# What subtype visa for settlement to apply for civil partner

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, immigration, uk-citizens

What subtype visa for settlement to apply for civil partner?

Which type of visa (settlement) to apply for where a person already has a civil partnership in the UK, is it family reunion?

If it is, what title should I put in applying for a settlement visa as I'm so confused on what to apply for (subtype-settlement) and I can't afford to make a mistake this time?

My situation is, I'm already married in the UK via civil partnership and I'm so confused on what to select under settlement category. My partner is a British citizen and I'm applying for this visa in the Philippines.

Comment: Rather than attempt to direct you, by a random stranger on the Internet, I'd suggest you follow the [excellent guidance provided by @GayotFow and others](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79358/uk-marriage-visitor-visa-mvv-refusal-and-subsequent-fresh-application) in response to your earlier question on SETravel. You already have one (if not two) visa refusals, and might be better assisted by a [UK Immigration Advisor](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79358/uk-marriage-visitor-visa-mvv-refusal-and-subsequent-fresh-application).